# How to set inner element border upon the outer one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
        .compare_header_box{
            padding: 35px 30px;
            direction: rtl;
        }
        .compare_header_box_title{
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 100px;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-top: 4px;
        }
        .compare_header_box_items{
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            direction: ltr;
        }
        .compare_header_box_items a{
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 15px 40px;
            
        }
        .compare_header_box_items a:hover{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            color: black;
        }
        .compare_header_box_items .active{
            border-top: 3px solid orange;
            border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-bottom: 1px solid white;
        }
```

```html
        <div class="compare_header_box">
            <span class="compare_header_box_title active">List</span>
            <div class="compare_header_box_items">
                <a href="./gp">gp</a>
                <a href="./in">in</a>
                <a href="./tw">tw</a>
                <a class="active" href="./fb">fb</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you see `border-bottom: 1px solid white;` doesn't seem to appear. I want to set it exactly upon the `border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;`. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Jegger something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxx4U.png

Answer (score 2):

Make use of **pseudo** elements,

```
.compare_header_box_items .active {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 3px solid orange;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.compare_header_box_items .active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
}
```

I hope this is what you require

```css
.compare_header_box {
  padding: 35px 30px;
  direction: rtl;
}

.compare_header_box_title {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.compare_header_box_items {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  direction: ltr;
}

.compare_header_box_items a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
}

.compare_header_box_items a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.compare_header_box_items .active {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 3px solid orange;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.compare_header_box_items .active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="compare_header_box">
  <span class="compare_header_box_title active">List</span>
  <div class="compare_header_box_items">
    <a href="./gp">gp</a>
    <a href="./in">in</a>
    <a href="./tw">tw</a>
    <a class="active" href="./fb">fb</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-bottom: -1px` to `a` tags in `.compare_header_box_items` div

Thus code will become:

```
.compare_header_box_items a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    margin: 0 0 -1px; /* add this line */
}
```

The reason your code not working is, main div border begin when inner links area ends which includes their borders too. Thus adding a 1 pixel negative margin will make them two borders overlap.

Answer (score 1):

As a hot fix, just add: `margin-bottom: -1px;`
check below code snippet.

```css
.compare_header_box{
            padding: 35px 30px;
            direction: rtl;
        }
        .compare_header_box_title{
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 100px;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-top: 4px;
        }
        .compare_header_box_items{
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            direction: ltr;
        }
        .compare_header_box_items a{
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 15px 40px;
            
        }
        .compare_header_box_items a:hover{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            color: black;
        }
        .compare_header_box_items .active{
            border-top: 3px solid orange;
            border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
            margin-bottom: -1px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="compare_header_box">
            <span class="compare_header_box_title active">List</span>
            <div class="compare_header_box_items">
                <a href="./gp">gp</a>
                <a href="./in">in</a>
                <a href="./tw">tw</a>
                <a class="active" href="./fb">fb</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) instead of `border`, which allows you to avoid shifting the positions of elements:

```
 box-shadow: 0 1px white;
```

(Note that I have substituted `red` for emphasis in the snippet below.)

```css
.compare_header_box {
  padding: 35px 30px;
  direction: rtl;
}

.compare_header_box_title {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.compare_header_box_items {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  direction: ltr;
}

.compare_header_box_items a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
}

.compare_header_box_items a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.compare_header_box_items .active {
  border-top: 3px solid orange;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 1px red; /* white; */
}
```

```html
<div class="compare_header_box">
  <span class="compare_header_box_title active">List</span>
  <div class="compare_header_box_items">
    <a href="./gp">gp</a>
    <a href="./in">in</a>
    <a href="./tw">tw</a>
    <a class="active" href="./fb">fb</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hyy
Only this things is possible and your problem will solve...

```
.compare_header_box_items .active {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -1px;
}
```

Add this css and your problem will solve.

Thanks :)

Appreciate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The white border seems to appear bro. But the background is also white. Change the background and you will see the white background or as part of your code you can just hover over it and check the border. To the result part, there are so many answers above. This answer is only to say that the border is visible and element next to it appears.

> Even SOF uses padding to fix it. If you remove, you will see border-bottom #CCC 
>   background.